# Can pipes be used across LAN computers?

Tags: c++, c, ipc, pipe

Can pipes be used across LAN computers?

In particular I'm looking for Windows, but if you have more info on other platforms, that will also help others who find this thread later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes they can.

> Named pipes can be used to provide
>   communication between processes on the
>   same computer or between processes on
>   different computers across a network.
>   If the server service is running, all
>   named pipes are accessible remotely

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365590.aspx

Comment: Obviously, not true for non-microsoft OSes.

Answer (score 4):

It should also be noted that a TCP/IP connection is effectively a pipe in the sense that you shove bytes in one end and they come out the other. TCP/IP connections are available on pretty much any platform you are likely to care about.

Comment: It should be noted because it's usually the correct way to do this in a non-Windows-specific way.